# Pause all woocommerce subscriptions for one week for maintenance

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a live website (build with wordpress and woocommerce) with some real subscriptions. These subscriptions are weekly recurring charges. In this site there are an option by which user can **PAUSE** or **RESUME** his/her weekly subscription. So now many **ACTIVE** and **ON-HOLD** subscriptions are there.

I want not to make any charges from users for only one week for some maintenance. I can't make all subscriptions **ON-HOLD** because of after maintenance I'm not able to separate **ACTIVE** and  **ON-HOLD** subscriptions.

I'm asking for any woocommerce settings for that on a particular week no payments/charges will occur without changing the subscription status(**ACTIVE** / **ON-HOLD**) and also notify users when they will visit the site about not charging.

Can any one help me to get out of this? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I got some satisfied answer [here](http://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201912997-Pause-all-woocommerce-subscriptions-for-one-week-for-maintenance#answer-203818037).

http://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201912997-Pause-all-woocommerce-subscriptions-for-one-week-for-maintenance#answer-203818037

Now I am trying with this.

Comment: Both of these URLs are broken now. Can you call back or reproduce what was suggested there?